# Add content editor web part to a sharepoint 2010 user control

Tags: c#, user-controls, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, content-editor

What's the best way to add a content editor web part into a user control?

I have created the user control with basic HTML just to get it to show some content. I have updated the master page to include the user control and so far the control is loaded correctly into the master page and I can see the sample HTML content/message I have added into the user control.

How do I then add a content editor web part into the user control?

I have created a test content editor and have exported it which gives me the DWP file. I can see then HTML inside the DWP file what the best way to them add this into the user control mentioned above?

Hopefully this is simpler to do than how I am describing it...

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way to do this..

Essentially I just created a user control and referenced it from the master page in the footer section.

In the code behind for the user control I am reading a html file stored in the Style Library and spit out onto the page via a content place holder

This works great and it allows for the content to the updated simply by updating the html file stored in the Style library